# grep command not returning all results

Tags: command-line, grep

I am running the following command but not all files that I know have this string are being returned and I cannot work out why. Specifically the apache log files which are under this path are not being returned.

```
grep -rl "eval(base64_decode('" /var/www | xargs ls -l
```

Can anyone point me to what I need to change to get these files returned too?

Comment: I am not sure , But i think you should try as root .

Comment: Nope if I sudo it I get the same results.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command. I tested the same and I'm able to get the results `$ sudo grep -rl "eval(base64_decode('" /var/www | xargs ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28 Dec 28 00:01 /var/www/drupal/themes/garland/deletethis1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34 Dec 28 00:00 /var/www/drupal/themes/garland/deletethis.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The script is fine. I guess that your Apache logs don't contain the text matching the pattern.

Comment: Strange. Log files definitely contain the string as I have search manually. Have to try something else I guess.